# Semantic Object in SAP FIORI

Tags: sap-fiori

During SAP Fiori Launchpad configuration we use semantic object.What is semantic Object and why it is used in SAP FIORI?

Thanks and Regards,

Teja

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 8):

On SAP Fiori Launchpad, navigation to tiles is done via "intents".

**What is an intent**: An intent is a unique combination of a semantic object (for example, Purchase Order) and an action (for example, Display) and an optional set of navigation parameters.

To summarize: When a user clicks a tile in their launchpad, the intent (including optional parameters) navigates to the app and opens it.

**Semantic Object**: Represents a Business entity(e.g Purchase Order) which represent an application in an abstract way by not focussing on implementation.

More information on Fiori Launchpad Objects here : https://help.hana.ondemand.com/cloud_portal/frameset.htm?18b3fc15e6fe487baa99be07c1da82c3.html

https://help.sap.com/viewer/17ae0e97e0fc424a9c368f350c0ba6bd/2.14/en-US/bd8ae3d327ab4541bcce8e7353c046fc.html

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer is that it allows you to map URLs to Fiori applications to objects in the Launchpad

Answer (score 1):

Semantic Object:
Represents a business entity such as a customer, a sales order, or a product. Using semantic objects, you can bundle applications that reflect a specific scenario. They allow you to refer to objects in a standardized way, abstracting from concrete implementations of these objects.
You can either use semantic objects shipped by SAP, or create new semantic objects.

Please see also [Configuring Navigation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/bd/8ae3d327ab4541bcce8e7353c046fc/content.htm?frameset=/en/60/9c84bbacb04fd8a17bdb5da742815f/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/bd/e12a271f0647e799b338574cda0808/plain.htm&node_id=83&show_children=false)